# How would you send a int array through winsock?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, winsock

So, I am just running some tests on sending encrypted messages through winsock (Yes, I know SSH does the same thing, just for fun.) But my problem is, in order to actually be able to encrypt with the method I'm using, I need something larger than just 8 bits (a char a array won't work here.) Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;




void __cdecl xorEncryptBytes(unsigned char bytesToEncrypt[], unsigned int byteBuffer[], unsigned int 
arrayLength, unsigned int encryptionKey, int shift) {

for (int _countNumber = (0); _countNumber <= (arrayLength); _countNumber++) {

    byteBuffer[_countNumber] = (bytesToEncrypt[_countNumber]);
};

for (unsigned int _countNumber = (0); _countNumber <= (arrayLength); _countNumber++) {

    byteBuffer[_countNumber] ^= (encryptionKey);
    byteBuffer[_countNumber] <<= (shift);
};

    return;
};
unsigned char* __cdecl xorDecryptBytes(unsigned int bytesToEncrypt[], unsigned char charBuffer[], 
unsigned int arrayLength, unsigned int encryptionKey, int shift) {

for (unsigned int _countNumber = (0); _countNumber <= (arrayLength); _countNumber++) {

    bytesToEncrypt[_countNumber] >>= (shift);
    bytesToEncrypt[_countNumber] ^= (encryptionKey);
};

for (unsigned int _countNumber = (0); _countNumber <= (arrayLength); _countNumber++) {

    charBuffer[_countNumber] = (bytesToEncrypt[_countNumber]);
};

    return (charBuffer);
};




int __cdecl main(void) {

unsigned char bytes[5] = ("sup?");
unsigned int byteBuffer[4096];
unsigned char charBuffer[4096];


xorEncryptBytes(bytes, byteBuffer, 5, 1, 2);


//-- How would I send the bytebuffer through?




std::cin.get();
return (0);
};
```

I know it's bad, just bear with me.

EDIT: I figured a solution, which is to use a bit-wrap shift function to wrap the bits around on shift, which eliminates the need for a bigger data type, thanks for your help!

Comment: `send(sock,byteBuffer,sizeof(byteBuffer),0);`

Comment: Yes, problem with this, is that you can't convert the type properly, as send takes a character buffer as an argument.

Comment: You can cast that pointer, but maybe you want some other solution?

Comment: `send(sock,(char*)byteBuffer,sizeof(byteBuffer),0);`

Comment: Well, you could, it's just the issue is when I shift left for the encryption, I can't decrypt it because the bits are shifted to far, and are deleted, so decrypting it is impossible. Casting it as a char will make it 8 bits once again. I'm making it a 32 bit int cause it eliminates 'bit wrapping' problems